# Fill input using stored data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use localStorage to fill an input field. I've used localStorage to store `weatherState`. Now when the user comes for the second time and start typing and if it match the `weatherState` value how can I make the input fill with `weatherState`. So basically it's like an ajax request to a database and showing values. How can I do this?

This is what I tried but I do not know how to do it?

```
$('#stateLocalInput').keyup(function () { //want to fill this field while typing
    if(localStorage.getItem('weatherState')==$(this).val()){
        $(this).val(localStorage.getItem('weatherState'));
    }
});
```

EDIT

I want to fill `$('#stateLocalInput').val()` by matching the input text to `localStorage.getItem(weatherState)`. E.g. If `weatherState` value is "NEW YORK" and the user starts typing "NE" , it should automatically fill as NEW YORK.

Comment: Missing `if`, `if (localStorage.getItem(weatherState)==$('#state').val())`

Comment: @Tushar Thank you. I've fixed that in my post. That doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @vistajess Thanks. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

As what have been said in comments, what you are looking for is :

```js
$('#stateLocalInput').keyup(function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  //user should type at least 2 character
  if(value.length > 1){
     if(localStorage.getItem('weatherState').substring(0,value.length) == value){
         $(this).val(localStorage.getItem('weatherState'));
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you want to do? if localStorage.getItem('weatherState')==$(this).val() condition is true, so input value is already same as weatherState! and you're trying to replace two equal thing with each other!

Comment: I want to fill `$('#stateLocalInput').val()` by matching the input text to `localStorage.getItem(weatherState)`. E.g. If `weatherState` value is "NEW YORK" and the user starts typing "NE" , it should automatically fill as NEW YORK.

Comment: I've edited my answer, please choose it if it's what you want.

Comment: Also, you may want to dynamically select the range from value.length to the item's length, otherwise the user may not notice and keep typing onto the end of NEW YORK, for example, he will type N, and then E, and then the input value will be NEW YORK, but he'll type W and then it will be NEW YORKW.  Honestly, I would just use a tried and true autofill library or jquery plugin and initialize it with the one value in localStorage.  Doing this manually is either a waste of time or, at best, a learning experience.